# How to rewrite url with 1 parameter

Tags: .htaccess

How to rewrite this links?

from

```
http://www.example.com/websitedevelopment.php?lan=en
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/websitedevelopment/en
```

---

and

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?lan=en
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/en
```

thanks..

Comment: Do you know the big search engine called google? Try there first...You will find tons of examples and answers

Comment: Ofc i try. There wasn't solution im looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^websitedevelopment/en$ websitedevelopment.php?lan=en [L]
RewriteRule ^en$ index.php?lan=en [L]
```

Comment: It works but after that my php cant catch GET parrameters from url and also all img was'nt found. What should i do?

Comment: What image? and on which page you are not able to get the parameter?

Comment: It's works i just need to change img src to full path. Thanks.